# Use other column values for Eloquent update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I would like to perform an `UPDATE` using Eloquent, that will set `column_c` value using values of `column_a` and `column_b` of the same table. Basically, something like this:

```
User::where('id', '>', 0)
        ->update(['column_c' => $this->column_a + $this->column_b]);
```

where `$this->column_a` and `$this->column_b` *would be* the actual values from the current row.

**MySQL equivalent:**

```
UPDATE `user` WHERE id > 0 SET column_c = column_a + column_b;
```

**Note**: The code above is just an example to show the idea. It's *not* the actual implementation (which would be creating a DB redundancy).

How do I perform such update in Laravel 5.1? I would really like to avoid a `foreach`.

Answer (score 39):

Maybe `DB::raw` can help. This will allow you to use any standard sql query to combine your data:

```
User::where('id', '>', 1)
    ->update(['column_c' => DB::raw( CONCAT(column_a, '-', column_b) )]);
```

Comment: Of course, I know `DB::raw()`, it's handy, but I find it to be a "workaround" for advanced queries, that are hard to build with Eloquent or Query Builder. It's quite disappointing that something that is so easily done in MySQL (as in my post) is unavailable out-of-the-box in Laravel. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: But I guess with Eloquent only there is only the way via querying the data first. As you said `DB::raw()` is something for advanced queries and I would call this already advanced as there are no functions like `concat` in laravel.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I will go with it in the end, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
User::where('id', '>', 0)
    ->update(['column_c' => DB::raw('`column_a` + `column_b`') ]);
```

Comment: A little more explanation and not only the code itself would have been nice. ;-)

Comment: I do not see a major difference from accepted answer, you changed id to 0 from 1 and replaced concat with + but that does not seem to make it a different solution to me.