# Laravel 8 Database Statement not being executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Trying to duplicate one column to another on MySQL using Laravel 8, the statement runs but values are not persisted.

```
DB::statement('UPDATE posts SET title = previous_title;');
```

Is there any solution to handle this case?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31118746/7498116

Comment: Please share more details

Answer (score -1):

DB uses your default database connection from config/database.php
DB credentials are mostly set in .env file.

When you use

```
DB::statement('UPDATE ....
```

the table is not specified anywhere and therefore it doesn't know on which table you want to make that update.

Solution 1

Use this to specify the table

`DB::table('table_name')->statement('UPDATE ....`

Solution 2

Use Eloquent because the table is set behind the scenes

```
User::update('column_name', NEW_ VALUE);
```

Have in mind this will update all rows on that table with same value if you don't use WHERE clause

Comment: I'm not sure if Eloquent can be used because I am getting error 'Non static method 'update' should not be called statically.'

Comment: DB::statement executes arbitrary raw SQL (w/ bindings). You do not specify a table when using it (other than in the query directly). DB::statement('SELECT NOW()') is perfectly valid. So is DB::statement("SELECT * FROM users'). That is also not the correct way to update a model using eloquent.