# How to update with function in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel

I'm doing a query and want to update the data, but I want to do a math operation first. How to simplify it?

my code below:

```
$jumlah = 10;
$Rpodetail = Rpodetail::where('rpo_id',$request->postore)->where('produk_id',$produkid)->first();
$total = $Rpodetail->sisa - $jumlah;
Rpodetail::where('rpo_id',$request->postore)->where('produk_id',$produkid)->update([
'sisa' => $total,
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jumlah = 10;
$Rpodetail = Rpodetail::where('rpo_id',$request->postore)->where('produk_id',$produkid)->first();
$total = $Rpodetail->sisa - $jumlah;
$Rpodetail->update([
    'sisa' => $total,
]);
```

Or

```
$jumlah = 10;
$Rpodetail = Rpodetail::where('rpo_id',$request->postore)->where('produk_id',$produkid)->first();
$Rpodetail->update([
    'sisa' => $Rpodetail->sisa - $jumlah,
]);
```

Or 1 line answer (According to @PBJ answer) with `DB:raw()` :

```
jumlah = 10;
Rpodetail::where('rpo_id',$request->postore)->where('produk_id',$produkid)->update(['
sisa' => DB::raw("sisa + '$jumlah'")]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do another query for updating, simply:

```
$Rpodetail->update(['sisa' => $total]);
```

[you can also use this answer for direct access to column values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118045/use-other-column-values-for-eloquent-update/31118746)